# pyarrow dataset partitioning by filenames converting filename to field/column name

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

Is there a way to use the filename in a dataset and have it be the column.

ie if the directory has

file1.parquet
file2.parquet
file3.parquet

can loading that as a dataset then have a column with the values file1, file2, and file3?

or does it only work with directory names?  It seems to only work with directory names, is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for filename-based partitioning will be in Arrow 8.0.0, which will likely release later this month or in May 2022. See [ARROW-14612](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14612). The same goes for being able to have a column with the filename, see [ARROW-15281](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-15281).

Comment: I don't think I understand the difference between filename based partitioning as a separate feature from having the filename get rolled up into a column name.  They seem like the same thing to me.  What am I missing?

Comment: Filename as a column is a more general feature.  As long as you have the filename you can probably do any of the partitioning tasks manually but filename partitioning is more specific and automatic.  For example, if your filenames look like `march_denver_part-0.parquet` then you can get columns `month` and `location` by specifying a partitioning.

Also, you will need to use a partitioning for any kind of write path where you want the filenames to be created automatically based on columns in your data.

Comment: ahhh I see so it'll be able to have multiple column names embedded in a filename.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To add on what @li.davidm said, you can now do:

```py
dataset = ds.dataset(
    "directory/",
    format="parquet",
)
columns_to_include = dataset.schema.names + ["__filename"]
scanner = dataset.scanner(columns=columns_to_include)
your_table = scanner.to_table()
```